# overlay image position changes during zoom out

Tags: wordpress, position, overlay, zooming

when I zoom out the webpage , the overlay image position changes.

how can I avoid these.
[Sample website is given below]

Demo website : [Netstrikers](http://netstrikers.comeze.com/?p=69)

website is created in wordpress.

my single.php code : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8ReWyLxu

Comment: Now the overlay image position changes in mobile browser and desktop browser,How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it and set position:relative. in content div..

```
<div id="content" style='position: relative;'>
   <div id="xx1" onclick="myFunction()">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YqqQj2x.png">
   </div>
   <.....>
</div>
```

Comment: @RaviBhanvadia: seems your ans works now thanks Ravi for your help.

Comment: Now the overlay image position changes in mobile browser and desktop browser,How to fix it?